# CLion: Enable compiler errors/warnings

Tags: cmake, clion

I am using CLion 2016.1.1 on Ubuntu (16.04)

When I compile my project, the CMake output shows:

```
/opt/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build 
/home/glapworth/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/project_name-f43e0982/f43e0982/Debug --target all -- -j 8
[ 33%] Linking C executable 
/home/glapworth/src/project/project_name/bin/project_name
```

However, when I execute:

```
/opt/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/glapworth/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/project_name-f43e0982/f43e0982/Debug --target all -- -j 8
```

I can see the compiler error:

```
...
CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/main.c.o: In function `main':
/home/glapworth/src/project/project_name/src/main.c:22: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
...
```

How can I get CLion to show the compiler errors or warnings?

Comment: If `cilon` not show compile error, then this is a bug in `clion`

Comment: Build with VERBOSE=yes and find the difference in the compiler invocation.

Comment: When I build with `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` I still don't see the error.  The compiler invocation is `/usr/bin/gcc    -Werror -Wall -g   -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/main.c.o   -c /home/glapworth/src/project/project/src/main.c` which is correct.  When running the same command from a terminal, I can clearly see the compiler errors.  It looks like STDERR is being redirected away from the Messages tab in CLion :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's bug-report https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6559

No, CLion shows all compile errors.  You can't compile a project if you have errors.

But, CLion shows notices only once during build time, until you make a clean build, you will not see them again. Because you have already compiled object files and CLion (CMake) will not rebuild them if you haven't changed source files.

CMake assumes you know what your'e doing and does not rebuild all your codebase from scratch, so you don't see notices after the first compile run.

Comment: If I understand correctly:  Build -> it shows errors.  Build again, and no warnings or errors. If I then perform a clean, then build it should show me the errors and warnings.  I've tried this, and it doesn't.

Comment: got it, too it's a bug. For me it looks like abruptly broken link-time message, I'll

Comment: @glapworth there's a temporary work-around here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6325

Answer (score 1):

It seems that CLion only shows the error on the first compile. If you've accidentally compiled a second time, you'll not be able to see the error output.  I've since moved back to vim.

However, if you want to stick with CLion, and you are having the same problem, you can build the `Makefile` manually; In the source directory that contains the CMakeLists.txt

`cmake .
make`

This will allow you to compile on demand from a terminal.

I also tend to set the build directoy to ./bin by editing the `CMakeLists.txt` to include the following line

`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your `CMakeLists.txt`. What does it look like? You can also try and clean your code, tool -> cmake -> refresh (both options) and have a regular `Makefile` that your build with so if Clion doesn't inform you about what's wrong then you can build with a regular `Makefile` . My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(project001)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
file(GLOB SOURCES "./*.c")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic")
add_executable(project001 ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(project001 readline)
```

My `Makefile` for the same project is

```
CC = gcc
GIT_VERSION := $(project001 git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --tags)
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -ledit -g -DVERSION=\"$(GIT_VERSION)\"

project001: main.o
    $(CC) -o project001 main.o errors.c util.c pipeline.c -ledit

main.o: main.c errors.c util.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

If Clion can't compile, then I fix the errors at the prompt and I use Clion to analyze my code so that it compiles without errors, then I can clean the project in Clion and run it from within Clion again.

Comment: Using the same CMakeLists.txt doesn't work. I only get error output on the first compile.  After that, just a % of the compilation is shown, where it stops.  This, is the same behaviour as before.  I've taken to compiling through the CLI, and I've moved back to vim.